# 2010 Town and Country electrical issues

Tags: electrical, door

My wife's 2010 Town and Country has developed a number of issues and I can't tell if they are all related much less how to fix them all.

1. The driver door and the driver side sliding door will often fail to unlock in response to the remote or the buttons above the rear view mirror. The lock button always works but the unlock button only works about 25% of the time. The front door will unlock with the physical key and the sliding door will unlock using the physical lock button on that door. Once unlocked the sliding door opens and closes without issue. I replaced the actuator on the front door with two different actuators from the junkyard and neither worked. I have not tried replacing the actuator in the sliding door.
2. The diverter under the dashboard will not change positions between the normal vents and the defrost vents. We had a similar problem a few months ago where it would try to change position but it didn't work because of a broken plastic piece. Our mechanic replaced that piece and it worked fine for a while. Now it won't change position at all.
3. When we use the upper DC outlet in the front of the van to power an air compressor to inflate the tires it blows the 10amp fuse after about 5 minutes. This has happened with two different compressors. Neither compressor causes an issue with other cars.
4. The passenger sliding door will not lock. No matter how hard I push the button on the door it will not lock, so I assume the actuator is seized or something similar.
5. The lift gate would not open. I fixed this by replacing the lift gate motor and gear.

I'm hoping that maybe issues #1 - #3 might point to a common electrical issue.

Comment: How many miles on this vehicle? Where has vehicle been for those past years?  Somewhere dry (Arizona) or somewhere in the rust belt with lost of corrosion?   It’s certainly possible a common electrical issue is causing those troubles but I doubt it.   E.g. A bad ground wouldn’t cause fuses to burn out. Note have you checked the aux power fuses in your other cars?  Are they larger then 10 amps?  Are you intending to make these repairs yourself?

Comment: These vans have a couple of very common issues for electrical problems.
1- The cables near sliding doors get rubbed and fray causing shorts and random problems.
2- TIPM failure.